# Messenger to Remote Service Causing Memory Leak

Tags: android, service, memory-leaks

I have an application that communicates with a `Service` in a remote process using the `Messenger` interface.  Here is the basic architecture of how things are set up:

- The application generates several "Operation" objects that require access to the service.
- Each "Operation" contains a `Handler` wrapped in a `Messenger` used to receive the response data back from the `Service`
- When the operation executes, it wraps its `Messenger` into an `Intent` and calls `startService()` to pass the message to the remote service
- The remote service does some work based on the parameters of the `Intent` and then returns the response by sending a `Message` to the `Messenger` for that operation.

Here is the basic code present in the operation:

```
public class SessionOperation {

    /* ... */

    public void runOperation() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(SERVICE_ACTION);
        /* Add some other extras specific to each operation */
        serviceIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, replyMessenger);

        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }

    private Handler mAckHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            //Process the service's response
        }
    };
    protected Messenger replyMessenger = new Messenger(mAckHandler);
}
```

And a snippet of how the Service is structured (it's basically an `IntentService` that doesn't shut down when the queue is empty):

```
public class WorkService extends Service {
    private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            onHandleIntent((Intent)msg.obj);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //If intent has a message, queue it up
        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.obj = intent;
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Messenger replyTarget = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL);

        /* Do some work */

        Message delivery = Message.obtain(...);
        replyTarget.send(delivery);
    }
}
```

This all works fantastically well.  I can send tons of operations from several different applications to the same service and they all process and send their response to just the right place.  However...

I noticed that if the application ran long enough and with enough activity it would crash with an `OutOfMemoryError`.  Upon looking at the HPROF data in MAT, I noticed that all these operations where staying in memory, and they were held hostage from the Garbage Collector because of the `Messenger`.  Apparently, the `Messenger` instance is creating a long-term native connection to Binder that counts as a GC Root, which is keeping each "Operation" object in memory indefinitely.

[image: MAT Trace Example]

Does anyone know if there is a way to clear or disable the `Messenger` when the "Operation" is over so it doesn't create this memory leak?  Is there perhaps another way to implement the IPC to the `Service` in the same fashion, so that multiple disparate objects can make a request and get a result asynchronously?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to some very helpful insight from Dianne Hackborn on the Android team, the issue is because the remote service process has not yet Garbage Collected it's instance of the Messenger which, in effect, held the instances in the application's process hostage until that time.

This is the text of her reply:

> It is true that sending a messenger across processes will require holding a GREF on it for the other process to communicate with it. Barring bugs (which have happened but I am not sure if in any released platform versions), the GREF will be released when the other process itself no longer holds a reference on this.  When we are talking about things in Dalvik "no longer holds a reference" generally means "the other side has garbage collected the Java proxy object."
>
> What this means is that when you throw a Messenger (or any IBinder object) across to another process, the Dalvik VM in your own process can no longer manage the memory of that object itself and is dependent on all remote objects releasing it until it can be released locally.  And this will include all objects that the IBinder has any references to as well.
>
> A common pattern to deal with this is to use a WeakReference in your IBinder/Messenger that holds the references to the rest of your objects that it will access.  This allows your local garbage collector to clean up all of those other objects (which may be quite heavy, holding big things like bitmaps and such) even though a remote process still has a reference on your IBinder.  Of course if you do this, there needs to be something else holding a reference on these other objects until they are no longer needed, or else the garbage collector could clean them up *before* they are no longer needed.
>
> Something else I would recommend is to not do a design where you instantiate Messenger objects for each IPC you do.  Create one Messenger that you pass in to each IPC call.  Otherwise you can generate a lot of remoted objects that are being kept around due to other processes continuing to hold references because the other side is not aggressively garbage collecting since all the objects it is creating due to these calls are small.

More Info:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/aK2o1W2xrMU/Z0-QujnU3wUJ

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best way since, even if `Activity` is in the background you will get the `message` from `Service`.

I think you should bind to the `service` and register a `messenger` to the service as soon as Service is connected. And then unregister the `messenger` when you disconnect.

Check [ExportVcardActivity](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/packages/apps/Contacts/src/com/android/contacts/vcard/ExportVCardActivity.java) in AOSP. It is following something along these lines.

Comment: Well, actually none of this happens in the context of an Activity, these are all completely background operations that need to stay bound to the Service until complete irrespective of what the user does.  Regardless, the memory leak still persists even if I use binding mechanism to access the Service rather than Intents.

Comment: You should not send the messenger by intents, but to register them after service is connected. And unregister when work is done