# Communication between Activity and Service causes memory leak

Tags: android, android-service, aidl

In my application I have a (background) `Service` which runs in its own process. To communicate with other components I defined some AIDL interfaces:

```
interface MyService {
    void addOnChangeListener(ServiceChangedListener listener);
    void removeOnChangeListener(ServiceChangedListener listener);
}

interface ServiceChangedListener {
    void onUserChanged(in User newUser);
}
```

Here is my service with the `MyService` implementation.

```
public class UserService extends Service {
    private RemoteCallbackList<ServiceChangedListener> listeners;

    public class ServiceBinder extends MyService.Stub {
        public void addOnChangeListener(ServiceChangedListener listener) {
            listeners.register(listener);
        }

        public void removeOnChangeListener(ServiceChangedListener listener) {
            listeners.unregister(listener);
        }
    }

    // all the other implementation...
}
```

My `Activity` connects to this `Service` in `onStart` and disconnects from it in `onStop` where it also release the listener which is registered in `onServiceConnected`.

```
public class MainAcitivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ServiceListener listener;
    private MyService service;

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, UserService.class);
        bindService(intent, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        try { service.removeOnChangeListener(listener); }
        catch (RemoteException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        unbindService(this);
    }

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        service = MyService.Stub.asInterface(service);

        try {
            listener = new ServiceListener();
            service.addOnChangeListener(listener);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class ServiceListener extends ServiceChangedListener.Stub {
        public void onUserChanged(User u) throws RemoteException {
            runOnUiThread(() -> { ... });
        }
    }
}
```

The add and remove methods for the listener simply operate on an `ArrayList` as you would expect so there is no long ongoing work.

LeakCanary as well as the Android studio memory analysis tool tell me that this causes a memory leak. If I comment out the lines affecting the listener no memory leak is detected. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: see `android.os.RemoteCallbackList` - use it as a container for remote callbacks

Comment: @pskink you mean instead of my ArrayList inside the add and remove methods? I did so but the problem persists...

Comment: use Android Lifecycle Architecture to handle this situration.https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html

Comment: ok so what leak do you mean? do you have balanced `register` / `unregister` method calls?

Comment: Yes I have. I only call them in the interface methods add and remove. The leak happens when I rotate the device. I added the Service implementation to the question.

Comment: so what's actually leaking?

Comment: In the analysis tool of Android Studio under leaked Activites `MainActivity$ServiceListener` is marked in blue so I think this is the object which holds a reference to the activity but I can't see why. I also added the `ServiceListener` class to the question.

Comment: `ServiceListener` is an inner class of `MainActivity`, so it holds a reference to the outer `MainActivity` instance. When you rotate the device, Android kills the instance of `MainActivity` and creates a new instance. The `ServiceListener` instance that you created in the first instance of `MainActivity` is probably still referenced from somewhere, even after the first instance of `MainActivity` is destroyed.

Comment: @DavidWasser thank you I will check for this. For this it should be enough to null the `listener` variable in `onStop` right?

Comment: I don't think so. If the `Activity` holds a reference to the `ServiceListener` and the `ServiceListener` holds a reference to the `Activity`, that isn't a memory leak. I assume that something else is holding the reference to the `ServiceListener`. What happens in `addOnChangeListener()`?

Comment: The code for `addOnChangeListener` is in the second code block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer! You have to make the inner class static and use a `WeakReference` within it. Here is an [official answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12206516/2047987) of a Google engineer and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24415772/2047987) a simplified one. Good luck anyone with the same problem!